# how to use QWinThumbnailToolBar to restore Taskbar Thumbnail after closing/opening vlc player in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, vlc, python-vlc

I am embedding python vlc in pyqt5 to make a video player.but i am having one problem that is when video starts to play it takes entire taskbar thumbnail to show only its video not other items present in the window screen.And after closing the video the taskbar becomes totally blank white, not showing anything.Here is picture samples.
1-Before Playing
[image]

2.When Playing(Look there is no button)
[image]
3.After Stopped[image]

I am trying to restore by

```
QWinThumbnailToolBar in self.videoframe.showEvent()
```

Here is my Complete Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWinExtras 
import vlc

class Player(QMainWindow):
    """A simple Media Player using VLC and Qt
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, master)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")
        self.mainframe=QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainframe)
        self.videoframe=QFrame(self.mainframe)
        self.videoframe.setGeometry(0,50,600,400)
        ##Call to set taskbar thumbnail
        self.videoframe.showEvent=self.setthumbnail
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.player.set_hwnd(int(self.videoframe.winId()))
        self.media = self.instance.media_new('C:/Users/mishra/Downloads/Video/kyakar.mp4')
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        button=QPushButton('Play',self)
        button.setStyleSheet('background:red')
        button.setGeometry(100,0,40,30)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda:[self.videoframe.show(),self.player.play()])
        button1=QPushButton('Close',self)
        button1.setStyleSheet('background:green')
        button1.setGeometry(200,0,40,30)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.onclose)
    def onclose(self):
        if self.player:
            self.player.stop()
        self.videoframe.hide()
    def setthumbnail(self,event):
        print('Shown')
        self.thumbbar =QtWinExtras.QWinThumbnailToolBar(self)
        self.thumbbar.setWindow(self.windowHandle())        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = Player()
    player.show()
    player.resize(600, 450)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I marked for you the lines I made the changes. Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWinExtras 
from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QWinThumbnailToolBar, QWinThumbnailToolButton
import vlc   
                                         

class Player(QMainWindow):
    """A simple Media Player using VLC and Qt
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")
        self.mainframe = QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainframe)
        
        self.videoframe = QFrame(self.mainframe)
#-        self.videoframe.setGeometry(0, 50, 600, 400)                               # ---
        self.videoframe.resize(640, 480)                                             # +++
        
# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv +++     
        # QWinThumbnailToolBar
        self.toolBar = QWinThumbnailToolBar(self)        

        # Prev, Play/Pause, Next
        self.toolBtnPrev = QWinThumbnailToolButton(self.toolBar)
        self.toolBtnPrev.setToolTip('Prev')
        self.toolBtnPrev.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipBackward))
        self.toolBtnPrev.clicked.connect(self.set_prev)
        self.toolBar.addButton(self.toolBtnPrev)

        self.toolBtnControl = QWinThumbnailToolButton(self.toolBar)
        self.toolBtnControl.setToolTip('Play')                       
        self.toolBtnControl.setProperty('status', 0)
        self.toolBtnControl.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.toolBtnControl.clicked.connect(self.set_control)
        self.toolBar.addButton(self.toolBtnControl)

        self.toolBtnNext = QWinThumbnailToolButton(self.toolBar)
        self.toolBtnNext.setToolTip('Next')
        self.toolBtnNext.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipForward))
        self.toolBtnNext.clicked.connect(self.set_next)
        self.toolBar.addButton(self.toolBtnNext)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ +++        
        
        
        # Call to set taskbar thumbnail
#-        self.videoframe.showEvent = self.setthumbnail                           # ---
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.player.set_hwnd(int(self.videoframe.winId()))
        self.media = self.instance.media_new('Samonastrojka.avi')                 # !!! <---
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        '''
        button = QPushButton('Play',self)
        button.setStyleSheet('background:red')
        button.setGeometry(100,0,40,30)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda:[self.videoframe.show(),self.player.play()])
        button1 = QPushButton('Close',self)
        button1.setStyleSheet('background:green')
        button1.setGeometry(200,0,40,30)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.onclose)
        
    def onclose(self):
        if self.player:
            self.player.stop()
        self.videoframe.hide()
        
    def setthumbnail(self,event):
        print('Shown')
        self.thumbbar = QtWinExtras.QWinThumbnailToolBar(self)
        self.thumbbar.setWindow(self.windowHandle())        
        '''
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def set_prev(self):
        pass

    def set_next(self):
        pass

    def set_control(self):
        if self.toolBtnControl.property('status') == 0:
            self.toolBtnControl.setToolTip('Pause')
            self.videoframe.show()
            self.player.play()
            self.toolBtnControl.setProperty('status', 1)
            self.toolBtnControl.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.toolBtnControl.setProperty('status', 0)
            self.toolBtnControl.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))        
            self.player.stop()
            self.toolBtnControl.setToolTip('Play')

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(Player, self).showEvent(event)
        if not self.toolBar.window():
            self.toolBar.setWindow(self.windowHandle())
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = Player()
    player.show()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: You dont get my point properly.i dont want those buttons(play,next,previous) in taskbar but i want my red and green button that shown in 1st image.cause when video is playing those buttons are already present in window then why it is not showing in taskbar thumbnail.And the second one when I click close button,the video stops and frame hidden,but the taskbar thumbnail remains complete blank, look my 3rd image you cant find those red and green button.My main point is VLC captures the entire thumbnail section and not allowing otherthings present in window to show.  @S. Nick